# Does "resume from standby" phrase sound natural?

Tags: word-request

I need to describe a mode of a machine or a device when it is ready for work but it is in kind of a sleeping mode. Also I need to put it in a context of "awakening" from such mode. 
The rough example is below.

> Tap on the screen for the system multimedia features to resume from standby.

The context is slightly technical, so I sought for a formal expression.
Even though the phrase "to resume from standby" is from the Microsoft site, I am not sure whether it is okay to use it in the context of some multimedia system.

Also there is the similar [topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/178119/is-standby-correct-for-waiting-for-orders) on ELL, but it couldn't answer my queries fully.

Comment: Your example is fine. In *some* contexts it would be reasonable to omit the ***from standby*** qualifier (if that was contextually implied to be the prior state). But it's best specified explicitly in your specific context, as you appear to have recognised with your *need to put it in a context of "awakening" from such a mode*.

Comment: I also like to see the goal stated first, but that's just a preference: *To resume from standby mode, tap on the screen.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other problems with your example, but "**resume from standby**" is not only a reasonable phrase, it's *actually a term that's used*, as you can tell by MS using it. It's not a Microsoft-specific term. It's two terms that have specific uses for computers and other electronics - people know what *resume* means, even if they haven't come across it with computers, and *standby* is well-known since we first got TVs with remote controls.

This is both formal and widely-understood. In some circumstances you might not need to bother with *from standby*, but including it is more formal.